# Combining aggregate and analytics functions in BigQuery to reduce table size

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am facing an issue that is more about query design than SQL specifics. Essentially, I am trying to reduce a dataset size by carrying out the following transformations described below.

I start with an irregularly sampled timeseries of Voltage measurements:

| Seconds | Volts |
| --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 2899 |
| 0.15 | 2999 |
| 0.17 | 2990 |
| 0.6 | 3001 |
| 0.98 | 2978 |
| 1.2 | 3000 |
| 1.22 | 3003 |
| 3.7 | 2888 |
| 4.1 | 2900 |
| 4.11 | 3012 |
| 4.7 | 3000 |
| 4.8 | 3000 |

I bin the data into buckets, where data points that are close to one another fall into the same bucket. In this example, I bin data into 1 second buckets simply by dividing the Seconds column by 1. I also add an ordering number to each group. I use the below query:

```
WITH qry1 AS (SELECT 
  Seconds
  , Volts
  , DIV(CAST(Seconds AS NUMERIC), 1) as BinNo
  , Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY DIV(CAST(Seconds AS NUMERIC), 1) ORDER BY Seconds) as BinRank
FROM
  project.rawdata
)
```

| Seconds | Volts | BinNo | BinRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 2899 | 0 | 1 |
| 0.15 | 2999 | 0 | 2 |
| 0.17 | 2990 | 0 | 3 |
| 0.6 | 3001 | 0 | 4 |
| 0.98 | 2978 | 0 | 5 |
| 1.2 | 3000 | 1 | 1 |
| 1.22 | 3003 | 1 | 2 |
| 3.7 | 2888 | 3 | 1 |
| 4.1 | 2900 | 4 | 1 |
| 4.11 | 3012 | 4 | 2 |
| 4.7 | 3000 | 4 | 3 |
| 4.8 | 3000 | 4 | 4 |

Now comes the part I am struggling with. I am attempting to get the following output from a query acting on the above table. Keeping the time order is important as I need to plot these values on a line style chart. For each group:

- Get the first row ('first' meaning earliest Second value)
- Get the Max and Min of the Volts field, and associate these with the earliest (can be latest too I guess) Seconds value
- Get the last row (last meaning latest Second value)

The conditions for this query are:

- If there is only one row in the group, simply assign the Volts value for that row as both the max and the min and only use the single Seconds value for that group
- If there are only two rows in the group, simply assign the Volts values for both the max and min to the corresponding first and last Seconds values, respectively.
- (Now for the part I am struggling with) If there are three rows or more per group, extract the first and last rows as above, but then also get the max and min over all rows in the group and assign these to the max and min values for an intermediate row between the first and last row. The output would be as below. As mentioned, this step could be associated with any position between the first and last Seconds values, and here I have assigned it to the first Seconds value per group.

| Seconds | Volts_min | Volts_max | OrderingCol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 2899 | 2899 | 1 |
| 0.1 | 2899 | 3001 | 2 |
| 0.98 | 2978 | 2978 | 3 |
| 1.2 | 3000 | 3000 | 1 |
| 1.22 | 3003 | 3003 | 2 |
| 3.7 | 2888 | 2888 | 1 |
| 4.1 | 2900 | 2900 | 1 |
| 4.1 | 2900 | 3012 | 2 |
| 4.8 | 3000 | 3000 | 3 |

This will then allow me to plot these values using a custom charting library which we have without overloading the memory. I can extract the first and last rows per group by using analytics functions and then doing a join, but cannot get the intermediate values. The Ordering Column's goal is to enable me to sort the table before pulling the data to the dashboard. I am attempting to do this in BigQuery as a first preference.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should do it

```
select Seconds, values.*, 
  row_number() over(partition by bin_num order by Seconds) as OrderingCol
from (
  select *,
    case
      when row_num = 1 or row_num = rows_count then true
      when rows_count > 2 and row_num = 2 then true
    end toShow,
    case 
      when row_num = 1 then struct(first_row.Volts as Volts_min, first_row.Volts as Volts_max)
      when row_num = rows_count then struct(last_row.Volts as Volts_min, last_row.Volts as Volts_max)
      else struct(min_val as Volts_min, max_val as Volts_max)
    end values
  from (
    select *,
      div(cast(Seconds AS numeric), 1) as bin_num,
      row_number() over win_all as row_num, 
      count(1) over win_all as rows_count, 
      min(Volts) over win_all as min_val, 
      max(Volts) over win_all as max_val, 
      first_value(t) over win_with_order as first_row,
      last_value(t) over win_with_order as last_row
    from `project.dataset.table` t
    window 
      win_all as (partition by div(cast(Seconds AS numeric), 1)),
      win_with_order as (partition by div(cast(Seconds AS numeric), 1) order by Seconds)
  )
)
where toShow
# order by Seconds
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]